# Regex is not working in Golang HandleFunc function

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to redirect the URL based on a pattern in Go. If my URL is containing "clientApi" then I am sending it to `clientApiPoint` func otherwise I am sending it to `redirectApiPoint` func. My `handleRequest` func is

```
func handleRequest()  {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    r.HandleFunc("/clientApi", clientApiPoint)
    r.HandleFunc("/{^((?!clientApi).)*$}", redirectApiPoint)
    http.Handle("/", r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

`{^((?!clientApi).)*$}` regex is working fine if my url is something like

```
localhost:8081/somerandonurl  (sending it to redirectApiPoint func)
```

but if there one or more "/" in the url, regex is not redirecting it to `redirectApiPoint` func.

```
localhost:8081/somerandonurl/somethingdifferent    (not sending it to redirectApiPoint. 404 page not found message)
```

Comment: [http.HandleFunc()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) can not be used to register a pattern to match a regular expression.

Comment: Are you taking the `/` into consideration? Also, you might not want to compile a regular expression every time the endpoint is hit - it's an expensive operation. Compile it elsewhere just once(if it won't change).

Answer (score 1):

your Regex work on "localhost:8081/somerandonurl" because of the first "/" so it matched.

you need somthing like "/(.*$)" but this will match any /blala/blala/...

you can test your regex from here:
[Regex](https://regex101.com/)